# How to show reflection of $\mathbb{S}^n$ and the identity are not homotopic?

Tags: manifolds, homotopy-theory, manifolds-with-boundary, compact-manifolds

Let $N=\mathbb{S}^n$, $M \subseteq \mathbb{S}^n$ be a hemisphere, including the equator (I am considering $M$ with boundary).

Let $f_1:M \to N$ be the inclusion map, and let $f_2:M \to N$ be the reflection of $\mathbb{S}^n$ w.r.t $\partial M$.

How to show $f_1,f_2$ are not homotopic through a boundary respecting homotopy?

i.e I want to show there is no homotopy which is constant on the equator $\partial M$.

(Can we use degree here? According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping#Differential_topology), the notion of a degree is defined only in case where the source is without boundary, or if the source has a boundary, then target must has one as well and the map must send boundary to boundary. In our case, the source has a boundary but the target does not).

Comment: As $M$ is contractible, and $N$ is path connected, all maps from $M$ to $N$ are homotopic. I suspect you want some extra conditions on your homotopies...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks, you are right of course. I forgot to mention I want the homotopy to be fixed on the boundary (corrected now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. OK. So you want to show, for instance, that the map $[0, 1] \to S^1 : x \mapsto (x, \sqrt{1-x^2})$ is not homotopic, rel boundary, to $[0, 1] \to S^1 : x \mapsto (x, -\sqrt{1-x^2})$

Such a map passes naturally to the quotient. $M$ is just the disk $D^n$,  so you get $f_i' : D^n /\partial D^n \to S^n / \partial M$, i.e., 
$$
f_i' : S^n \to S^n / \partial M.
$$
The space $K$ on the right is the union of two $n$-spheres that meet at a single point (i.e., a sphere with its belt snugged up). Now $H_n(K) = Z \oplus Z$, by the homology sequence of a pair, with $U$ being the (image under the quotient map of) upper sphere plus the arctic region of the lower one, and $V$ being the lower sphere plus the antarctic region of the upper. 
More formally: 
$$
U = \{ (x_0, \ldots x_n) | x_n > -\frac{1}{2} \}\\
V = \{ (x_0, \ldots x_n) | x_n < +\frac{1}{2} \}.
$$

Furthermore, the induced maps on homology are $Z \to Z \oplus Z : u \mapsto (1, 0)$ and  $u \mapsto (0, 1)$. And since homotopic maps induce the same map on homology, $f_1'$ and $f_2'$ are evidently not homotopic.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer! My topology is a bit rusty, so I have some questions: (1) If I understood you correctly your argument is that if there was a boundary respecting homotopy, then it would descend to the quotient, so the induced maps $f_1',f_2'$ would be homotopic, right? (2) How can you see that the $f_i'$ are the generators? (Does the fact $\pi_n(K)=Z \oplus Z$ is due to [Hilton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilton's_theorem) or is there a more elementary approach?) This is intuitively clear but I don't see it rigorously.

Comment: Wait...I totally lied about $\pi_n(K)$. It's *not* as simple as $\pi_n (S^n) \oplus \pi_n(S^n)$. The point is that the two inclusions generate non-homotopic maps...let me rewrite. Sorry about this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still don't understand two things, though: (1) By a homology sequence of a pair, do you mean [this](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Long_exact_sequence_of_homology_of_a_pair)? If so, then what are $A,X$ here? ($U,K$, $V,K$? $U$ is not a subspace of $V$...).  (2)  How can you see that the $f'_{i}$ are the generators? Thanks again.

Comment: The "pair" I meant was $(K, U)$, so $\to H_{n+1}(U) \to H_{n+1}(K) \to H_{n+1}(K, U) \to H_{n}(U) \to H_{n}(K) \to H_{n}(K, U) \to H_{n-1}(U)$; since $U$ deformation retracts to an $n$-sphere, this gives us  $\to 0 \to H_{n+1}(K) \to H_{n+1}(K, U) \to \Bbb Z \to H_{n}(K) \to H_{n}(K, U) \to 0$. And since homology of the pair $K, U$ is a lot like the homology of $K$ with $U$ contracted to a single point (for nice spaces), which is just another sphere, we can flesh this out to  $\to 0 \to H_{n+1}(K) \to 0 \to \Bbb Z \to H_{n}(K) \to \Bbb Z \to 0$. Does that help a bit?

Comment: To see those things are generators, you can actually observe that $S^n$ is topologically just the boundary of $\Delta^{n+1}$, so to make $S^n \vee S^n$, we can take  two $n+1$-simplices that share a single vertex. Now the (simplicial) homology groups really are pretty straightforward, and it's clear that the things I described really are generators. If you work this out in detail for $n = 1, n = 2$, I think you'll be convinced.